# Styled Components get values from string prop

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdmt-sc-columns-1njrnq?embed=1&file=index.tsx)

I'm trying to create a column layout using styled components

I was trying to pass the widths of the columns in the props.

Is it possible to get values from a strig prop passed to the component

So if I pass

```
<PageLayout twoCol="60,40">
```

I'd like to get the values something like

```
flex-basis: ${props.twoCol.split(',')[0]}'%';
```

I thought it's s string so can I use split to get the separate values in the string.

This doesn't work. is there another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
const PageLayout = styled.div`
  flex-basis: ${(props) => props.twoCol.split(",")[0]}%;
`;
```

But a better option might be passing the values instead of manipulating a string:

```
<PageLayout twoCol={[60,40]}>

const PageLayout = styled.div`
  flex-basis: ${(props) => props.twoCol[0]}%;
`;
```

The main problem with your snippet is that you need to write a real **CSS** inside the string literal:

```
// not '%' like ${(props) => props.someProp}'%'
flex-basis: ${(props) => props.someProp}%;
```